# Position h1,h2,h3 and other tags with TCPDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to make a PDF document with TCPDF using HTML code.

At the moment I use this code:

```
// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 36);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = '
<style>
.h1 {
color: #2B6999;
font-weight: normal;
}

</style>

<h1 class="h1">Test</h1>

';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, 'C');
```

How can I position this text? I cannot use between the  tags margin-top etc..

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 12):

You can add something like this:

```
$tagvs = array('h1' => array(0 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 3), 1 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 2)),
               'h2' => array(0 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 2), 1 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 1)));
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
```

And here is the format description from the docs / examples:

File: tcppdf.php :

```
/**
 * Set the vertical spaces for HTML tags.
 * The array must have the following structure (example):
 * $tagvs = array('h1' => array(0 => array('h' => '', 'n' => 2), 1 => array('h' => 1.3, 'n' => 1)));
 * The first array level contains the tag names,
 * the second level contains 0 for opening tags or 1 for closing tags,
 * the third level contains the vertical space unit (h) and the number spaces to add (n).
 * If the h parameter is not specified, default values are used.
 * @param $tagvs (array) array of tags and relative vertical spaces.
 * @public
 * @since 4.2.001 (2008-10-30)
 */
```

File http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.phps :

```
// REMOVE TAG TOP AND BOTTOM MARGINS
//
// $tagvs = array('p' => array(0 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0), 1 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0)));
// $pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
// 
// Since the CSS margin command is not yet implemented on TCPDF, you
// need to set the spacing of block tags using the above method.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using writeHTML which outupts the HTML exactly, you need to use the "`$pdf->Cell`" function. There are lots of example on this here http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: How can I set margin or x/y position from a cell? I found this line: $pdf->Cell(0, 110, 'TEST CELL STRETCH: no stretch', 0, 1, '', 0, '', 0);

Comment: check this example: complex alignment with Multicell()